# Multitask gestures not working with alert

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

After UIViewAlert has become visible, multitask gestures cannot be used. How can I fix it? Is it a normal behavior?

EDIT:

Looks like creating custom view is a good idea. I just wanted to know, if it can be done nice and easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, UIAlerts are designed to occupy the whole focus of the device. If you want to allow gestures, try creating your own UIView that overlays on top of your running application.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I've done some research, looks like you are right. With no Internet, Safari shows alert, gestures not working. However, in my situation it is a good move to allow user quickly change application. Can it be done. somehow?

Comment: Are you building an application inside Safari, if so you could use a Fancybox in place of a standard JS alert();

Comment: You will need to build essentially a fake alert by creating your own UIView.

Answer (score 1):

When UIAlertView appears, its freeze whole screen. You can't get the touch on screen thats why your gesture is not working. First dismiss the alert view then your gesture will work.

Comment: But you can show bar with launched apps, by swiping 4 fingers from bottom. Why 4 fingers swipe left or right is not working?